# Excel format row

Tags: c#, excel

I will create an Excel file with a Name, a date and a Code for "my" privat run competition.

It works fine but it looks not so nice. How can I format the cells for to read the insert date and text ?
The Name and the Content could not be read at all 
[image: Excel sample screenshot]

```
Excel.Application _xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook _xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet _xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    internal void CreateExcelFile(string writePath)
    {
        this.CreateHeader();
        this.AddContent();
        this.SaveFile(writePath);
    }
    private void CreateHeader()
    {
        _xlWorkBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        _xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        _xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, ExcelObject.SAMNAME] = "SAM_NAME";
        _xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, ExcelObject.DATE] = "Date";
        _xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, ExcelObject.CODE] = "Code";
        FormatCells(_xlWorkSheet.Cells.Borders);
    }
    private void AddContent()
    {
        int i = 1;
        ++i;
        _xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, ExcelObject.Date] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        _xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, ExcelObject.SAMNAME] = "Julek";

    }
    private void FormatCells(Excel.Borders _borders)
    {
        _borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        _borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        _borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        _borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
        _borders.Color = ConsoleColor.Black;
    }
    private void SaveFile(string writePath)
    {
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.xls","SampleFile", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"));
        _xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Path.Combine(writePath, fileName), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue,
           misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        _xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        _xlApp.Quit();

        ReleaseObject(_xlWorkSheet);
        ReleaseObject(_xlWorkBook);
        ReleaseObject(_xlApp);
    }
    private void ReleaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please specify what you want to achive? Do you want to format you data so that Excel could recognize it as a date?

Comment: I want to create a Excel file where all runners are automatically inserted for the helper in the competition. So, it would be great if they can read all Names, titles and so on without format the Excel file manually.

Comment: If I can give you one tip, use EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for generating/editing Excel files. It has very intuitive methods for everything about style, adding DataTable, column width, columntype, celltype etc. etc. and can be installed easily through Nuget. It has method for `AutoColumnWidth` etc. which is simply awesome for most simple excel files :)

Comment: @invidicult I've posted the answer which should help you to save dates without formatting it to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the formatting for the whole column and use the `ToOADate()` method instead of the `.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")`:

```
// get the date cell
Range rg = _xlWorkSheet.Cells[ExcelObject.DATE, ExcelObject.DATE];
// specify the format for the whole column
rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = @"yyyyMMdd\_HHmmss";

// ...

//  write the current date
_xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, ExcelObject.DATE] = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
```

I've changed the format from `yyyyMMdd_HHmmss` to `yyyyMMdd\_HHmmss`, because Excel would convert `_`to a whitespace and `\` keeps the underscore as it is.

The width of the column can be automatically changed in this way (call this method in the end of the editing):

```
rg.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

The `AutoFit` method should be called in the end when all data were inserted. It changes the width only once when it was called, but not continuously.

Comment: I have a short question to this, it works fine but the width for the column will be formatted for the title width, not for the inserted date with...how can I change this ?

Comment: The `AutoFit` method should be called in the end when all data were inserted. It changes the width only once when it was called, but not continuously.

Comment: @invidicult could you please check whether the updated updated answer works for you and accept this answer only if it solves the issue.

Comment: The problem was that i called the method after creating the header...it works now, thanks!